# How to unselect selectall checkbox if any of the check box is unselected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've a check all checkbox where it check all the checkboxes once it is checked and vice-versa for uncheck .

How to uncheck the check all checkbox if any of the checkbox is unselected and check the check all check box if all the checkboxes are selected.

```
<form action="#">
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/> Check all</label></p>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Loads of checkboxes</legend>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 1</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 2</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 3</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 4</label></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

```js
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/89anugaz/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add a click handler to the lower checkboxes you can compare the total number of checkboxes to the number of checked checkboxes. Try this:

```js
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});

$('.checkbox').change(function() {
  $('#checkAll').prop('checked', $('.checkbox').length == $('.checkbox:checked').length);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <p><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/> Check all</label></p>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Loads of checkboxes</legend>
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /> Option 1</label></p>
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /> Option 2</label></p>
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /> Option 3</label></p>
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /> Option 4</label></p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: If all checkboxes are selected by clicking every checkbox,check all is not checked